# How can I load something with jQuery after the rest of the page has loaded?

Tags: jquery

I have a page with a lot of pictures and content to load, and have added a jQuery function that adds a transition class on load to create a simple text animation. Because the content can take quite a while to load, I wanted to make sure the class was added after all the pictures etc had loaded first, so I tried using both of these code snippets below. They both seem to have the desired effect, but only once - when I refresh the page again, the class is not added. Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.header').addClass('tilt');
});


$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $('.header').addClass('tilt');
});
```

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Both your option are ready when DOM is ready. After reload it works too. Loaded DOM doesn't mean that all other assets (images) are loaded.

Comment: To achieve that you have to loop through all the images on the pages and read the real size and the downloaded part to measure or show progress.

Comment: "When I refresh the page again" - how are you "refreshing the page"?  A simple F5 will always run doc.ready but will also run as soon as the DOM is ready for manipulation, not after the page is "loaded" (hence doc.ready, not doc.loadCompleted).  It could be that you do some other manipulation to get the `.header` elements to load and these might be running after your doc.ready.  We'd need a [mcve] to see it happening to advise without guessing.

Comment: I'm refreshing with ctrl R or the button in the browser. I've just tried recreating the problem in jsFiddle and it's not happening there. Strange.. I'll have to look into it further.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to **run** CSS transitions after the page load and JS-execution, you should wait at least 2 repaint frames:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {

      // To run CSS-Transition add your class here

    });
  });
});
```